# MS Bot c# Custom Vision prediction endpoint error in Bot "The given path’s format is not supported."

Tags: c#, botframework

have created a simple project demonstarting custom vision object detection. All is working well. But the issues comes when I attach image via Bot chat, it throws Exemption saying

```
The given path’s format is not supported...
at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks(String fullPath)
at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare
```

Here is the full code...

```
 public class Vision:IDialog<Object>
 {
     Guid ProjectId = Guid.Empty;

     const string PredictionKey = "<MY KEY>";

     public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
     {
         context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);

         return Task.CompletedTask;
     }

     private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
     {
         await context.PostAsync("Hello there. Nice to meet you!");
         context.Wait(ResumeAfterOperationSelecting);

     }

     private async Task ResumeAfterOperationSelecting(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
     {
         PromptDialog.Attachment(
             context: context,
             prompt: "Upload Image to perform operation",
             resume: ResumeAfterRecievingAttachment
         );
     }

     private async Task ResumeAfterRecievingAttachment(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IEnumerable<Attachment>> result)
     {
         var images = await result;

         foreach (var image in images)
         {
             ProjectId = new Guid("<MY PROJECT ID>");

             PredictionEndpoint endpoint = new PredictionEndpoint() { ApiKey = PredictionKey };

             var results = endpoint.PredictImage(ProjectId, File.OpenRead(image.ContentUrl));

             foreach (var c in results.Predictions)
             {
                 await context.PostAsync($"{c.TagName}, {c.Probability}");
             }

         }
         await context.PostAsync("Hello there. Have done!");

         context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
     }

}
```

so the error happens on this line

```
var results = endpoint.PredictImage(ProjectId, File.OpenRead(image.ContentUrl));
```

here is the full exemption message

```
 The given path’s format is not supported.     
 at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks(String  fullPath)
 at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
 at System.IO.FileStream…ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
 at SimpleEchoBot.Dialogs.Vision.<ResumeAfterRecievingAttachment>d__5.MoveNext()
 in C:\Users\AbdiHakim\Music\reres-src\Dialogs\Vision.cs:line 55
 — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume1.<Rest>d__5.MoveNext()
 in D:\a\1\s\CSharp\Library\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\Dialogs\DialogTask.cs:line 164 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- 
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) 
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) 
 at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait2.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IWait<C>-PollAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
 in D:\a\1\s\CSharp\Library\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\Fibers\…
```

What should I do with this line. Since according to my opinion Microsoft Bot Framework may not allow System.IO to reald file Image attachment. If so, how can I implement it so that the Prediction point URL can read the Image URL of the bot attachment.

> ```
> NOTE: Prediction endpoint requires the method to have format like this..
> ```

endpoint.Prediction(,)

Output on Json Bot Framework Emulator is this

```
 "type": "message",
  "attachments": [
    {
      "contentType": "image/jpeg",
      "contentUrl": "blob:file:///a3f2d3e1-e295-46fe-b434-b05f3905301c",
      "name": "11.jpg"
    }
  ],
```

Comment: here is the out Json I have seen in emulator

Comment: "type": "message",
  "attachments": [
    {
      "contentType": "image/jpeg",
      "contentUrl": "blob:file:///a3f2d3e1-e295-46fe-b434-b05f3905301c",
      "name": "11.jpg"
    }
  ],

Comment: What makes you think https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openread(v=vs.110).aspx handles a string that looks like that?

Comment: can you help me then !

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what type of file your URL is pointing too (Azure blob storage?).  The message is clear through -- File.OpenRead does not support the type of file you're trying to access **blob:file://**.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openread(v=vs.110).aspx

Here are is a [list of acceptable paths from MSDN:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx)

> In members that accept a path, the path can refer to a file or just a directory. The specified path can also refer to a relative path or a Universal Naming Convention (UNC) path for a server and share name. For example, all the following are acceptable paths:
>
> "c:\MyDir\MyFile.txt" in C#, or "c:\MyDir\MyFile.txt" in Visual
>   Basic.
>
> "c:\MyDir" in C#, or "c:\MyDir" in Visual Basic.
>
> "MyDir\MySubdir" in C#, or "MyDir\MySubDir" in Visual Basic.
>
> "\\MyServer\MyShare" in C#, or "\MyServer\MyShare" in Visual
>   Basic.